# InvalidElementStateException on element that is visible and interactable

Tags: selenium, geb

Element:

```xml
<input
    class="DFLeft valid"
    id="Input_329"
    name="EsigFirstName"
    style="width:225px;"
    type="text"
    aria-labelledby="Input_329Label"
    value="twoEEm"
    maxlength="255"
    data-val="true"
    data-val-required="Required."
    data-val-length="Min 0 characters required."
    data-val-length-max="255"
    aria-required="true"
>
```

Geb Navigator:

```java
firstNameTextBox(wait:true) {
    $(
        $(name:"SigFirstName"),
        $(name:"ESigFirstName"),
        $(name:"EsigFirstName")
    ).module(TextInput)
}
```

I've checked:

1. No element is displayed on top of input
2. Element text can be edited manually
3. Geb Navigator successfully returns 1 element
4. Converting Geb Navigator to jquery selector successfully returns 1 element

Full stack trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state:
Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated Driver
info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{
    applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false,
    chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),
    userDataDir=C:\Users\dclark\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6964_14861},
    takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false,
    version=56.0.2924.87, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
    webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true
}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:273)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.clear(RemoteWebElement.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.WebElement$clear$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.setInputValue(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:668)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor145.invoke(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1121)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1152)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1121)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator$_setInputValues_closure41.doCall(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:646)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor144.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1121)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:439)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2027)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2012)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2053)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
    at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.setInputValues(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:645)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor142.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1121)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.value(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:423)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor92.invoke(Unknown Source)     
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)   
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)  
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1121)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
    at geb.module.TextInput.setText(TextInput.groovy:27)    
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor371.invoke(Unknown Source)    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)   
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2699)   
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.setProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1181)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3746)   
    at geb.Module.setProperty(Module.groovy)    
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:192)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.putAt(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:268)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$508.invoke(Unknown Source)   
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:248)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at geb.content.TemplateDerivedPageContent.propertyMissing(TemplateDerivedPageContent.groovy:136)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor163.invoke(Unknown Source)    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2721)   
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.setProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1181)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3746)   
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.setProperty(DelegatingMetaClass.java:170)
    at geb.content.TemplateDerivedPageContent.setProperty(TemplateDerivedPageContent.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:192)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:482)
    at com.stuff.qa.es.page.ShoppingEnrollEnrollmentFormAcceptCoveragePage.Usersignsapplication(ShoppingEnrollEnrollmentFormAcceptCoveragePage.groovy:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)   
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)  
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1121)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:914)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:897)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:166)
    at geb.Browser.methodMissing(Browser.groovy:207)    
    at geb.Browser$methodMissing$14.call(Unknown Source)    
    at TestScript.methodMissing(ConsoleGroovyTemplate.groovy:84)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:933)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1256)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1209)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1121)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at TestScript.runScript(ConsoleGroovyTemplate.groovy:43)    
    at TestScript$runScript.call(Unknown Source)    
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:114)
    at ConsoleGroovyTemplate.run(ConsoleGroovyTemplate.groovy:119)  
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:261)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:522)    
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:501)    
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:168)    
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$run$1.call(Unknown Source)   
    at groovy.ui.Console$_runScriptImpl_closure17.doCall(Console.groovy:984)
    at groovy.ui.Console$_runScriptImpl_closure17.doCall(Console.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)   
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)  
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1121)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)   
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)   
    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:504)    
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Maybe try looking closer at the `html` in and around this `input` you're trying to interact with. 9 times out of 10 when I see something like this, it's because there is some other element in the dom that is the one I need to interact with, and the obvious option actually isn't what I wanted.

Comment: When you get the returned element, print out the outerHTML and see if it's the element you were expecting. I don't know geb but in other languages it's typically something like `someElement.getAttribute("outerHTML")`.

Comment: Hey Doug, I have just repaired and code-formatted your completely unreadable stack trace. Next time please don't insert it as a word-wrapped quoted text. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The geb page I was at extended a geb page that was visited previously in the spock spec. Issue was resolved by duplicating the navigators to the child page.

My thoughts are that the parent page (which was visited first) had resolved the navigator and the child could not find the previously resolved navigator.

Can someone verify or correct me? I dislike that I have to duplicate this code.